C++ function returning by value can return rvalue reference?
I was reading up on rvalues and ran into something while trying a code snippet on compiler explorer. Here's a contrived example:
class A
{
    public:

    A&& func(A& rhs)
    {
        //return rhs;
        return std::move(rhs); //returning A&&
    }
};

vs
class A
{
    public:

    A func(A& rhs)
    {
        //return rhs;
        return std::move(rhs); //returning A&&
    }
};

I was expecting this second snippet to fail to compile because of return type mismatch. Func's return type here is A whereas what it's actually returning is A&& courtesy of std::move(). I have tried latest versions of gcc, clang and msvc. All have this same behaviour. Can someone please explain what's going on here?

If we assume the move constructor is used, we can check that is actually the case: https://godbolt.org/z/eMbcqPnhj

You are confusing value category and type. You are not returning A&&, you are returning an rvalue of type A.

"because of return type mismatch" -- Mismatches are not as strict as you seem to think. Have you ever tried something like float one() { return 1; }? That is, a function that returns a float, but the return statement is given a different type (an int value) to return?

Sideways comment - avoid using std::move to return values because it can prevent RVO (return value optimisation) - see C++ weekly 404 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SaUwqw4ueE)

Related, maybe a future question in this learning experience: How to avoid the "pessimizing-move" warning of NRVO?

@JaMiT In your example 1 (int) gets implicitly converted to float because it's an allowed conversion. By that rationale, it would mean an rvalue reference to a type gets implicitly converted to type? That feels odd

@san216 "it would mean an rvalue reference to a type gets implicitly converted to type?" -- The default move and copy constructors are implicit, correct. If you don't want them to be implicit (which might cause other problems, though), you could declare them to be explicit with explicit A(A&&) = default; and explicit A(const A&) = default;.

@JaMiT I am not even taking about which constructor should be called. I am talking about static type checking that should come first during the compilation. Unless the claim is X&& is not a different type than X. Template type deduction, overload resolution would disagree with this claim.

@san216 "I am not even taking about which constructor should be called. I am talking about static type checking that should come first during the compilation." -- This is a contradiction. Determining which constructor should be called is a part of the static type checking. It needs to be, because whether or not that constructor is flagged explicit determines whether or not an implicit conversion is allowed. (Try it: flagging the move constructor explicit would make your second snippet fail to compile.)

@JaMit. Got your point, see my update. And thanks a lot!

@san216 I rolled back your edit because if you'd like to post a solution it should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question. Also please see: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

In C++, when you use std::move on an object, you're not actually converting it into an rvalue reference (T&&). Instead, you're casting it to an rvalue, which signals the compiler that it can treat the object as a temporary and, if possible, move from it instead of copying. However, std::move does not alter the underlying type; it merely provides a hint for the compiler to use move semantics.
Here’s what’s happening in both examples:
Example 1: A&& func(A& rhs)
In this version, the function func returns an A&& (an rvalue reference to A). When you return std::move(rhs), you're directly returning an rvalue reference, which matches the return type A&&. This makes sense and will compile as expected.
Example 2: A func(A& rhs)
In this case, the function func has a return type of A, which is a value (not an rvalue reference). However, when you return std::move(rhs), you're still casting rhs to an rvalue reference (A&&). Here’s why this still compiles and behaves as you observed:

Automatic Conversion: When you specify a return type of A (a value), the compiler expects to create and return an A object. If you provide an A&& (via std::move(rhs)), the compiler interprets this as an instruction to move-construct an A from rhs rather than copy it. The compiler sees that rhs is an rvalue and uses the move constructor to construct the return value.

Return Type Deduction and Temporary Materialization: The compiler will implicitly perform a move when returning an rvalue if the return type is by value. In this case, A func(A& rhs) specifies a return type of A, so the compiler treats std::move(rhs) as an rvalue, creating a temporary A using the move constructor.



"when you use std::move on an object, you're not actually converting it into an rvalue reference (T&&)." std::move is literally just a cast to T&&. The only reason it's provided as a function at all, rather than having the cast explicitly in code, it to avoid the repetition of the type T.

@jayashankar Casting means forcing the compiler to interpret one type as another. Unless the cast is illegal, compiler will go ahead with the new (cast) type. I, logically speaking, I'd assume static type checking as part of the syntax check will come first first. Whether the compiler should call move or copy constructor or RVO, should come later?

@ArthurTacca The answer is correct. Expressions never have reference types, so std::move only changes the value category to an rvalue, and not the type.

@HolyBlackCat Even if it's technically correct in a language lawyer sense, I'd say it's misleading in an introduction/summary like this. They've said "you're not actually converting it into ... T&&" for something that is literally defined as static_cast<T&&>.

@ArthurTacca Yep, I also don't understand why the answer brings it up...

More to the point, the distinction (if there is one) just isn't relevant here. The point that matters to this question is that C++ is allowed to do an implicit conversion from the x in return x to the value actually returned, so it's converting from T&& (or rvalue to T or whatever you want to call it) to an actual T value using the constructor (although that copy/move construction may be elided).

@ArthurTacca This comment helped. Thank you!


I was expecting this second snippet to fail to compile because of return type mismatch.

There is no problematic mismatch here.
In your 2nd case the function returns a rvalue of type A.
This return value will be used with the move constructor of A to construct the A instance on the caller side.
This is demonstrated below:
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A()                              { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; };
    ~A()                             { std::cout << "dtor\n"; };
    A([[maybe_unused]] A const & a)  { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; };
    A([[maybe_unused]] A && a)       { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; };

    // To respect the rule of 5 we also need copy and move operator=, 
    // but it is omitted here for the example

    static A func(A& rhs) {
        //return rhs;
        return std::move(rhs); //returning A&&
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    A a2 = A::func(a1);
}

Output:
default ctor
move ctor
dtor
dtor

Live demo
If you don't supply a move constructor the compiler will generate it.
